# Can I connect from sql server 2000 client to sql server 2008 server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a customer that has a system that uses sql server 2000 as a database server. each client uses sql server 2000 client to connect to the database server. for now we needs to Migrate the sql server 2000 database to work under sql server 2008. I just want to know if there is a way to get sql server 2000 clients on client machine connect to the database server after upgrading to sql server 2008, or I will have to install sql 2008 client on each client application. I mean is there any way or workaround to get sql 2000 client to connect to sql server 2008 server.

Many thanks for help,
Hassan Ali

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the application(s) can continue to use the SQL 2000 client connectivity (e.g. MDAC) to connect to the 2008 server. You would, however, be well advised to avoid using any 2005/2008 features within the database, until such time as you update the application(s) to use SQL Native Client.

You shouldn't need to make any changes or apply any workarounds for this to work.

---

The above is true for "general" applications. What won't work, however, are applications that use [DMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131540.aspx). Those applications would have to be updated to use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).